# How to load data from a CSV file, manipulate it, and write it to another CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm just getting my feet wet with Python and have been looking for the answer for the past few hours. I have a CSV file with a list of all lowercase names as rows. I'm trying to capitalize the first letter of each and save it to a new file. Here's what I have so far but I can't get it to manipulate the data in the CSV.

```
import csv

input_file = open('file_to_read.csv', 'rb')
output_file = open('file_to_write.csv', 'wb')

reader = csv.reader(input_file)
writer = csv.writer(output_file)

for row in reader:
    data = row.capitalize()
    writer.writerow(data)

input_file.close()
output_file.close()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'capitalize'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`capitalize` is the method of string but not the method of list.

Use `data = [x.capitalize() for x in row]` instead

Comment: This worked but I had to change it to `data = [x.capitalize() for x in row]`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've fixed it

Comment: Please let me know the reason for -1

Comment: Wasn't me. I don't even have enough rep to upvote yet.

Answer (score 4):

It's telling you the truth.  `row` is a list (one element for each column).  You can call, e.g., `row[0].capitalize()` but you can't call `capitalize()` on the list because this isn't a valid list operation.

If you want to capitalize all the columns in the row, you could do this:

```
row = [col.capitalize() for col in row]
```

Given:

```
>>> row = ['one','two','three']
```

This gets you:

```
>>> row = [col.capitalize() for col in row]
>>> row
['One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. My data is many rows and 1 column though, so wouldn't I want to work with the rows and not the column?

Comment: You still can't apply the `.capitalize()` method to a list -- even if there's only a single column, it's still a list; the `capitalize` method is only available on strings.  So again, you can call `row[0].capitalize()`, but not `row.capitalize()`.

Comment: Right, that's what I did to get it to work in my comment above.